# C# Script Source Equivalent/Alternative in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

I have an SSIS package that I'm trying to deploy in Azure but I've ran into some permission issues.

I have 2 question:

1. Does Azure have a Script Source equivalent?
2. Are there alternatives to using a SSIS and run my C# Script?

Sorry if super vague but bascially I have an C# script that I want to use a datasource, it gets data from 2 web apis on is Sharepoint Online and the other is Excel Online, and copy it to a Azure Sql Database.

I've tried deploying the SSIS-IR but ran into some permission issues.

I thought I could run an activity but I don't think it supports C# scripts as a source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Azure Data Factory Custom Activity](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/commit/60fa54bad499a8f42455a212aeaa7eb6b8940d13) to run C# code. [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/) is an alternative to SSIS on Azure.